# How can I slice a string like Python does in Perl 6?

Tags: string, slice, roles, raku

In Python, I can splice string like this:

```python
solo = A quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog
solo[3:5]
```

I know `substr` and `comb` is enough, I want to know if it's possible, However. Should I use a role to do this?

Answer (score 14):

### How to slice a string

Strings (represented as class `Str`) are seen as single values and not positional data structures in Perl 6, and thus can't be indexed/sliced with the built-in `[ ]` array indexing operator.

As you already suggested, [`comb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/comb) or [`substr`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/substr) is the way to go:

```perl6
my $solo = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

dd $solo.comb[3..4].join;   # "ui"
dd $solo.comb[3..^5].join;  # "ui"

dd $solo.substr(3, 2);      # "ui"
dd $solo.substr(3..4);      # "ui"
dd $solo.substr(3..^5);     # "ui"
```

If you want to modify the slice, use [`substr-rw`](https://doc.perl6.org/routine/substr-rw):

```perl6
$solo.substr-rw(2..6) = "slow";
dd $solo;  # "A slow brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

### How to make operator `[ ]` work directly on strings

If you really wanted to, you could compose a role into your string that adds method [`AT-POS`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts#method_AT-POS), which would make the `[ ]` operator work on it:

```perl6
my $solo = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" but role {
    method AT-POS ($i) { self.substr($i, 1) }
}

dd $solo[3..5]; ("u", "i", "c")
```

However, this returns slices as a list, because that's what the `[ ]` operator does by default. To make it return a concatenated string, you'd have to re-implement `[ ]` for type `Str`:

```perl6
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]>(Str $string, Int:D $index) {
    $string.substr($index, 1)
}
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]>(Str $string, Range:D $slice) {
    $string.substr($slice)
}
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]>(Str $string, Iterable:D \slice) {
    slice.map({ $string.substr($_, 1) }).join
}

my $solo = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

dd $solo[3];     # "u"
dd $solo[3..4];  # "ui"
dd $solo[3, 5];  # "uc"
```

You could extend the `[ ]` multi-candidates added here to handle [all the other magic](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts.html) that the operator provides for lists, like:

- from-the-end indices, e.g. `$solo[*-1]`
- truncating slices, e.g. `$solo[3..*]`
- adverbs, e.g. `$solo[3..5]:kv`
- assignment, e.g. `$solo[2..6] = "slow"`

But it would take a lot of effort to get all of that right.

Also, keep in mind that overriding built-in operators to do things they weren't supposed to do, will confuse other Perl 6 programmers who will have to review or work with your code in the future.

Comment: nice job, to be honest, I will not really rewrite these methods. I just want to know whether Perl 6 can achieve it. Perl 6 is Awesome!

Comment: A better idea is to use another pair of brackets to do the thing (something outside the ASCII range will do the trick).