# Why does a Perl 6 Str do the Positional role, and how can I change []?

Tags: role, raku, multimethod

I'm playing around with a positional interface for strings. I'm aware of [How can I slice a string like Python does in Perl 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41689023/2766176), but I was curious if I could make this thing work just for giggles.

I came up with this example. Reading positions is fine, but I don't know how to set up the `multi` to handle an assignment:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s, Int:D $n --> Str ) {
    $s.substr: $n, 1
    }
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s, Range:D $r --> Str ) {
    $s.substr: $r.min, $r.max - $r.min + 1
    }
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s, List:D $i --> List ) {
    map( { $s.substr: $_, 1 }, @$i ).list
    }

multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s, Int:D $n, *@a --> Str ) is rw {
    put "Calling rw version";
    }


my $string = 'The quick, purple butterfly';

{ # Works
my $single = $string[0];
say $single;
}

{ # Works
my $substring = $string[5..9];
say $substring;
}

{ # Works
my $substring = $string[1,3,5,7];
say $substring;
}

{ # NOPE!
$string[2] = 'Perl';
say $string;
}
```

The last one doesn't work:

```
T
uick,
(h   u c)
Index out of range. Is: 2, should be in 0..0
  in block <unit> at substring.p6 line 36

Actually thrown at:
  in block <unit> at substring.p6 line 36
```

I didn't think it would work, though. I don't know what signature or traits it should have to do what I want to do.

Why does the [`[]`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postcircumfix_[_]) operator work on a [Str](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str)?

```
$ perl6
> "some string"[0]
some string
```

The docs mostly imply that the `[]` works on things that do the [Positional](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Positional) roles and that those things are in list like things. From the [`[]` docs in operators](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postcircumfix_[_]):

> Universal interface for positional access to zero or more elements of a @container, a.k.a. "array indexing operator".

But a `Str` surprisingly does the necessary role even though it's not an `@container` (as far as I know):

```
> "some string".does( 'Positional' )
True
```

Is there a way to test that something is an `@container`?

Is there a way to get something to list all of its roles?

Now, knowing that a string can respond to the `[]`, how can I figure out what signature will match that? I want to know the right signature to use to define my own version to write to this string through `[]`.

Comment: But, the same thing doesn't happen with and `Int`, for instance. It doesn't do Positional.

Comment: you're misusing `.does` - it expects a type object (or, looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/43c1767/src/core/Mu.pm#L703..L705), an arbitrary object whose type it will compare against) and not a name: `"some string".does( 'Positional' )` is equivalent to `"some string".does( Str )`, not `"some string".does( Positional )`

Comment: Then `.does` should complain about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is by augmenting the `Str` class, since you really only need to override the `AT-POS` method (which `Str` normally inherits from `Any`):

```
use MONKEY;
augment class Str {
    method AT-POS($a) {
        self.substr($a,1);
    }
}
say "abcde"[3];     # d
say "abcde"[^3];    # (a b c)
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#Methods_to_implement_for_positional_subscripting

Answer (score 4):

To make your `rw` version work correctly, you first need to make the Str which might get mutated also `rw`, and it needs to return something which in turn is also `rw`.  For the specific case of strings, you could simply do:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s is rw, Int:D $i --> Str ) is rw {
   return $s.substr-rw: $i, 1;
}
```

Quite often, you'll want an `rw` subroutine to return an instance of `Proxy`:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[ ]> ( Str:D $s is rw, Int:D $i --> Str ) is rw {
   Proxy.new: FETCH => sub { $s.substr: $i },
       STORE => sub -> $newval { $s.substr-rw( $i, 1 ) = $newval }
}
```

Although I haven't yet seen production code which uses it, there is also a `return-rw` operator, which you'll occasionally need instead of `return`.

```
sub identity( $x is rw ) is rw { return-rw $x }
identity( my $y ) = 42; # Works, $y is 42.

sub identity-fail( $x is rw ) is rw { return $x }
identity-fail( my $z ) = 42; # Fails: "Cannot assign to a readonly variable or a value"
```

If a function reaches the end without executing a `return`, `return-rw` or throwing an exception, the value of the last statement is returned, and (at present), this behaves as if it were preceded `return-rw`.

```
sub identity2( $x is rw ) is rw { $x }
identity2( my $w ) = 42; # Works, $w is 42.
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a module that aims to let you do this:

https://github.com/zoffixznet/perl6-Pythonic-Str

However:

> This module does not provide Str.AT-POS or make Str type do Positional or Iterable roles. The latter causes all sorts of fallout with core and non-core code due to inherent assumptions that Str type does not do those roles. What this means in plain English is you can only index your strings with [...] postcircumfix operator and can't willy-nilly treat them as lists of characters—simply call .comb if you need that.`